# scanf function for reading full line input using ^\n

Tags: c

What is the difference between

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", str_1);
```

and

```
scanf("%[^/n],str_2);
```

I am trying to read a full line as an input using `scanf` function, the first one works fine but as soon as I remove the space between `"` and `%` the function takes no input.

Comment: `/n` is a literal string `/n` while `\n` is a new line. And don't tag both C and C++, they're different languages

Comment: Use `fgets()`.  `scanf(" %[^\n]",` without a width limit is worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", str_1);
```

This will skip whitespace (until it finds a non-whitespace character) and then start reading characters into `str_1` until it reaches a newline or EOF.  It will not do any bounds checking, so may overflow the storage for `str_1`.  If an EOF is read before finding a non-whitespace character, it will return 0 without writing anything into `str_1` (not even a NUL character).

```
scanf("%[^/n],str_2);
```

This will read characters other than `/` and `n` into `str_2` until it sees either a `/` or `n` or an EOF.  Like the first one, it does not do any bounds checking so may (will likely?) overflow the storage of `str_2`.   If the first character of input is either a `/` or a `n` (or EOF) it will fail to match the pattern at all, returning 0 and not storing anything into `str_2` (not even a NUL terminator).

Basic scanf semantics -- whitspace in the format string will skip 0 or more whitespace characters in the input until a non-whitespace character is reached to start whatever the next pattern is.  `%[` matches characters with no bounds checking, so should never be used with untrusted input -- you should always use an explicit bound or `m` modifier.

If you want to read lines of input (as opposed to whitespace delimited words, ignoring differences between newlines and other whitespace), you should use `fgets` or `getline`